# Getting Records With Unique Phone Number

Tags: mysql

I have a nice little query that works.  It queries a single "Clients" table

Here is the table:    SQLFiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fcea

```
CREATE  TABLE `clients` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `foo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

INSERT INTO`clients` (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) VALUES ('Jim', '123 Main', 'MO', '876', '2038221661');
INSERT INTO`clients` (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) VALUES ('Tom ', '234 Elm', 'MO', '433', '2038221661');
INSERT INTO`clients` (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) VALUES ('Steve', '653 Pine', 'CT', '863', '5125901977');
INSERT INTO`clients` (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) VALUES ('Dave', '654 Oak', 'NV', '872', '8769085435');
INSERT INTO`clients` (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) VALUES ('Oscar', '622 FIrst ', 'LA', '625', '5125551212');
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       address, 
       phone 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) 
       AND foo > 40 
ORDER  BY foo
```

It Returns:

```
2   Tom     234 Elm     2038221661
5   Oscar   622 FIrst   5125551212
3   Steve   653 Pine    5125901977
1   Jim     123 Main    2038221661
```

I dont want want our customer service people calling any place more than once.  So  I need to return only distinct phone numbers.

I need it suppress (1) Jim  and Return

```
2   Tom     234 Elm 2038221661
5   Oscar   622 FIrst   5125551212
3   Steve   653 Pine    5125901977
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       address, 
       phone 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) 
       AND foo > 40 
       AND id in 
       (
          select min(id) from clients group by phone
       )
ORDER  BY foo
```

Comment: Nope  Not sure what up:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id in ( select min(id) from clients group by phone ) OR' at line 8: SELECT id, name, address, phone FROM clients WHERE state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) AND foo > 40 AND phone in id in ( select min(id) from clients group by phone ) ORDER BY foo

Comment: Please use my updated query. In the old one I had `in` twice.